# Eslint rule to detect a missing return in a TypeScript method block

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have the following es-lint related packages...

```
"@angular-eslint/builder": "14.0.2",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.2",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.2",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.0.2",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.2",

"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.29.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.29.0",

"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "39.3.3",
"eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
```

I am already using `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`, however this does not pick up the following in my Angular/TypeScript project...

```
private receivedDataFromServer(state: MyState, data: ServerData[]): MyState {
  const methodName = `${moduleName}.receivedDataFromServer`;
  try {
       
    // No return type, and no error to warn me
  } catch (error) {
    this.logger.error(`${methodName}): ${Utils.unknownTypeToString(error)}`);
    return state;
  }
}
```

So I have forgotten to return something in the main body (the only return is in the exception)

Is there an `es-lint` rule for this?

Comment: Well that _should_ be a type error, `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.(2366)` See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgIJwN7DnADgJwJYDdIAXAUzi2NGP2IBMARIyAMSwHsBbAZWKzx4AoAlAC440QrgB2AcxRp0cCQE85ChQHp1cAHKsyxQgFcskxUozEANHEiSacSXp5ssivQHdIJuO2Lz0AL5woESgABZw-M6sWIKqavpG3gDkhGE8pJ7wtnDRWMkA3P5wAfKlAUA

Comment: Ah ok, yes I have added `"noImplicitReturns": true,` to my tsconfig.json. You could add this as an answer and I will mark it as the solution